# Lebesgue measure/integral, set translations, characteristic functions..

Tags: integration

I have this tough problem that I could use some help with. Consider two Lebesgue integrable sets $A,B$ such that $\infty>\mu(A)>0\mu(B)>0$. Prove we can find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A\cap(x+B))>0$.

Since we are to prove something exissts, I'm guessing the right way to approach this is by contradiction. So I let $\mu(A\cap(x+B))=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This means $\int_{A\cap(x+B)}d\mu=0$ for all $x$, or that $\chi_A *\chi_{-B}$ has zero integral.

Is this right? Does this lead somewhere?
Any help...? Any hints?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also Lebesgue's density theorem lol

Comment: What do you mean...? Is this a theorem?:)

Comment: What you have obtained is $\chi_A * \chi_{-B}=0$ at every point. Integrate this equation. Since $\int f*g=(\int f) (\int g)$ you get $\mu (A) \mu (B)=0$ which is a contradiction.